# EditText Issue - Android

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, android-studio

I want to change a value from a simple editText in android studio. This will happen on create event. Unfortunately, I have no clue why my code is not working. Here is my current code:

Starting Activity:

```
public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button loginButton,signupButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        }
    });

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        }
    });
}
```

Problematic activity:

```
import ..

public class SignupActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    EditText usernameEditText;
    EditText firstnameEditText;
    EditText lastnameEditText;
    EditText emailEditText;
    EditText repeatemailEditText;
    EditText birthdateEditText;
    Button nextButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        firstnameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameEditText);
        lastnameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastnameEditText);
        emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        repeatemailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repeatemailEditText);
        birthdateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthdateEditText);

        usernameEditText.setText("something here"); //not working

    }
}
```

the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tryme34.example.com.app.SignupActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:text="test" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/firstnameEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lastnameEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstnameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lastnameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/repeatemailEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/birthdateEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/repeatemailEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/birthdateEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your layout please where the EditText is defined?

Comment: Sure, I did the edit.

Comment: as ive seen in the [src-of-EditText](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/EditText.java#55) it is already editable.

Comment: try `Log.i("Test" , usernameEditText.getText());` after `usernameEditText.setText("something here");` if it outputs `something here` then your layout must been overlapped by other Views

Comment: if i run it from any emulator, it will pop up the message on my android Studio console? never tried log.i thats why i am asking.

Comment: it will pop up in [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: i edited this: Log.i("Test" , usernameEditText.getText().toString());
then run it from my nexus S emulator. Checked my logcat console, nothing was written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start a new activity for new layout 
 EDIT: In Your Start Activity

replace

```
 signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        }
    });
```

with

```
signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent a = new Intent(StartActivity.this,SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
```

Comment: have tried & checked that before I posted, it is not working in my problem

Comment: i just copy paste your code and for my convince just replaced ActionBarActivity to Actvity and it runs fine as you see in the edittext

Comment: what you mean, exactly?

Comment: i am trying to say that For Each Layout , use a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your EditText to say something in it, like a hint for what information should go there, you should use the hint tag in the xml definition:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:hint="something here"
/>
```

Comment: I want to settle my text on events (like on click etc), change dynamicly, not keep it static

Comment: the hint is just the grayed-out text that appears originally to let the user know what information goes in the edittext.  Beside that, your code is correct - the correct method for setting the text in an EditText would be .setText().  You should probably remove the 'android:text="test"' line from your xml definition

Comment: Tried this, still the same problem

Comment: @Try_me34 you need to post your entire activity with all of your code - something is awry here - this shouldn't be that difficult of a problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok so silly of me. I wasnt calling right my new activities. The problem wasnt on editText, but it was on my starting activity. Fixed Code:

```
public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button loginButton,signupButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for help, it was useful.